# How can I modify the Chipolo circuit to support earlier versions of Android?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I have been trying to find out more of the circuit design of [Chipolo](http://www.chipolo.net/) and would like to modify it so that it can support earlier Android versions because it can only support Android running version 4.3 or newer.

May I know where can I find the circuit design and hints on how I can change to the circuit design to support earlier Android versions (Android running version 2 up to 4.2)?

Comment: It uses Bluetooth Low Energy which is not compatible with classic bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

You can't; it's not a problem with the circuit. Android 4.3 added support for the Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) protocols used by this device. Earlier versions don't support BTLE, and most of the phones running earlier versions won't have the appropriate Bluetooth chips to support it anyway.

Comment: This. To make it work, you have to modify *the phone*.